# How to pass the value of PK to FK

Tags: mysql, foreign-key, primary-key, mysql-workbench, default-value

Ok, so here it goes. I have a table called employee. then I have another table called languages. I need to copy the value of PK of employee table to foreign key in Languages table, rather than entering it manually. So, whenever a new employee is added, I need the value of the EmployeeID, so that I can add the language details. Suppose, the employee knows 2 lanuages, I just add two language details for the same employee.

So, in the end I need something similar to the picture[image]

I hope I could explain the problem this time
Regards

[image]

Comment: At least I don't understand your question. Can you might give some example or something?

Comment: @frlan I just need to pass the value of primary key of one table to foreign key in another.

Comment: What have you done so far?

Comment: You might want to look at [this - last_insert_id() function](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/information-functions.html#function_last-insert-id) - there is a PHP function [mysql_insert_id()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/mysql-insert-id.html) - don't know if there's an equivalent in JS.

Comment: Confusing question. You should know what the PK is. If you don't know, select it and then you will know.

Comment: I forgot to add - "could you please clarify your scenario, voting to close until question is expanded upon".

Comment: @Vérace, I've updated the question